# Whats the different between Logistic regression and perceptron?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, logistic, neural-networks, perceptron

In a binary classification problem, if both logistic regression and a single preceptron uses Sigmoid function, what's the difference in

1. classification results, since they will have the same decision boundary ?
2. their conceptual behaviour?

Comment: related https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/137834/clarification-about-perceptron-rule-vs-gradient-descent-vs-stochastic-gradient/137847#137847

Answer (score 1):

Their mechanics are the same, one neuron, uses linear combination of features, with intercept option and logit (sigmoid) function. Conceptually, they both try to find a hyperplane. If you also use the same loss function, they'll respond similarly.

One difference is that a typical logistic regression implementation uses [Newton Conjugate Gradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method_in_optimization) solver (that uses Hessian matrix), while in neural net implementations this is not provided as an option due to its computational complexity. See `sklearn` implementations and `solver` options: [logistic-regression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html), [MLP](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html).

Comment: we can use the same loss? see this discussion If you also use the same loss function, they'll respond similarly.